# How to set the cursor position to initial position of a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text field within in a div. In my case the width of the text field is more than the width of the div. So I have used `overflow: hidden` for the div(UI modification not possible now). I have also a 'Clear' button which will clear the text field.

Now the issue i am facing is,

1. Type a long string in the text field.
2. Now click on the clear button to clear the text.
3. Now when you will type something again, you will find that the first character is hidden from the UI. But later when you press `Home` you will be able to see the complete text. In Chrome it works fine I guess , i found the issue in firefox.

Here is the simple example,

```js
$('#but').on("click", function() {
  $("#fname").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv" style="width:100px; overflow: hidden;border: 2px solid black; margin:20px">
  <input type="text" id="fname" style="width: 250px;border: 5px solid red;">
</div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="clear">
```

Is there any way I can fix it, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your div has 150px and the input 250px, so the overflow it will cut from the input, this is why you see :

[image]

But when you type more characters into the input the browser will to its best to display the text you are typing in, and pushes the input to do so.

[image]

On clear by doing `$("#fname").val("");` there is nothing that instructs the browser to reposition the input, so the browser keeps the UI for the input unchanged.

[image]

So to retest it completely you would need to reposition the input in the `overflow:hidden` container.

For example, set the width of the input smaller than the container and then set it back to original value:

```js
$('#but').on("click", function() {
  $("#fname").val("");
  $("#fname").width(0); // setting the width smaller then the container 
  // deffer
  setTimeout(function (){
    $("#fname").width(250); // setting the width to original value
  }, 50);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv" style="width:100px; overflow: hidden;border: 2px solid black; margin:20px">
  <input type="text" id="fname" style="width: 250px;border: 5px solid red;">
</div>
<input type="button" id="but" value="clear">
```

Comment: Not working. This have the same issue that I explained.

Comment: Try now, I've added a longer time to reset : 10ms instead of the typical 0ms to defer

Comment: I've retested and works sometimes,  a 50ms defer time works 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can set a focus after clearing the field, then the cursor will be set to the initial position.

**Try this:**

```
$('#but').on("click", function() {
  $("#fname").val("");
  $("#fname").focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yk48hoqm/

Comment: The input is not repositioned when you enter a text longer than the input and then click on clear button. I think he wants to reposition the input as well to the original state.